# What is "I bet" in German?

Tags: phrase-request

In English I always find myself saying "I bet" in this kind of context: "I bet you're well chuffed with it." What would this be in German and could it be used without sounding weird?

Comment: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher?

Comment: Was heißt chuffed with it?

Comment: "Well chuffed" = höchst erfreut, mit einem Element der Überraschung.

Comment: *Blown away* kinda like?

Comment: Yes, blown away is the best description.

Comment: Eine weitere, idiomatisch besser passende Übersetzung wäre "ich schätze, damit hast du nicht gerechnet". https://context.reverso.net/%25C3%25BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/hast%2Bdamit%2Bgerechnet

Comment: Und noch eine weitere Möglichkeit wäre *bestimmt* - Du bist bestimmt überrascht, dass das so ist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are numerous ways to say it.

Most natural to me sounds (colloquially)

> Wetten, dass er sich gleich blamiert? *Wanna bet, that he's going to make a fool of himself?*

Which is short for

> Wollen wir wetten, dass er sich gleich blamiert?

Which can also be used.
As flopana has mentioned, you can also use

> Ich wette, er blamiert sich gleich / Ich wette, dass er sich gleich blamiert.

Lastly a famous earlier TV show was also called "Wetten, dass?", where contestants in the show would bet, they could do something extraordinary and famous guests then had to say how they plead. If the guest lost the bet, they often had to do a humiliating task.

Answer (score 5):

In german "I bet" is "Ich wette", and definitely yes: you can use it in a sentence the same way you would in english.

> I bet he will stumble and fall.
>    ⇆ 
>   Ich wette, er wird stolpern und fallen.

Comment: Beistrich fehlt: *Ich wette, er ...*

Answer (score 1):

It should be "Ich wette" in german.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Please note that we already have two answers that say "Ich wette". Thus, please only answer, if you can expand on existing answers or add something new.

Answer (score -5):

I would much rather say ***ich hoffe***, "I hope". *Ich wette* is closer to *betcha* and implies a challenge. The expression is optionally negated, unlike *I bet*, but the conjunctive *I wouldn't bet on it* works analogously. *Ich würde nicht darauf hoffen*. The level of politeness may differ, though.

> a) I bet he's gonna fall on his face
>
> Ich hoffe er fällt auf die Schnauze

This works well, but the next bit looses in translation.

> b) I bet you are well chuffed with it
>
> Ich hoffe, das überrascht dich
>
> I expect you be surprised
>
> Ich erwarte, dass du überrascht bist

Better would be ***Ich nehme an***, "I suppose, I take it that ...", which incidentally covers *Wetten annehmen*, "to take bets".

As such, "ich wette, du platzt gleich!" would be not only sarcastic, but provocative and thus highly impolite. If you are frequently imposing yourself, then *Ich wette damit hast du nicht gerechnet* is indeed a fitting translation for the style.

---

Comparing *hoffen* to *bet* makes sense semantically, but etymologically I find *hoffen* quite difficult (that is I had a counterintuitie hint at a derivation), while *bet*, that might have come under influence of various lexically not too distant words, is no easier.

Comment: Ehm nein? Das ist ja eine komplette fehl Übersetzung.

Comment: @infinitezero ich hoffe nicht, Sie hätten auch noch Argumente um Ihre Position zu untermauern.

Comment: Es taucht zum Beispiel nicht als Übersetzung auf: http://Dict.cc?s=Bet davon abgesehen: hoffen drückt aus, dass du dir etwas wünscht. Das muss bei wetten nicht gegeben sein. Wetten bedeutet, dass du es dir den wahrscheinlichsten Ausgang hälst. (Es kann Ausnahmen geben, dass man bewusst auf etwas unwahrscheinliches wettet, zwecks der besseren Quote).

Comment: @infinitezero was vollkommen unerheblich ist, da es sich hier um eine idiomatische Phrase, nicht das lexikalische Element handelt. Sonst wäre die Frage auch unzulässig. Zudem behauptet kein Lexikon Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit. Meine Antwort kann zudem nicht falsch sein; Ich weiß wohl besser wie ich spreche, als Sie. Natürlich könnte dem ein falsches Sprachverständnis zugrunde liegen, das kann aber dict.cc zumindest kaum aufzeigen. Das Problem ist. *I bet* ist in .com recht häufig und durch *betcha* beeinflusst, *Ich wette* in .de aber weniger, daher ist etwas Deutung notwendig.

Comment: Oh Entschuldigung, wenn sie sowas besser wissen hätten sie das vorher erwähnen müssen, dann hätte ich meine Antwort direkt gelöscht. Das wusste ich nicht.

Comment: @infinitezero "sowas"? Willst du jetzt wettern weil die Antwort stark kontextabhängig ist?

Comment: Wirre Argumentation vom Beantworter.

Comment: An alle, die hier Löschung vorschlagen: Gelöscht soll nur werden, was keinen Versuch darstellt, die Frage zu beantworten. Für schlechte oder falsche Antworten sind Downvotes da.

Comment: @sfg, das stimmt so nicht. Bei der Option **very low quality** steht als Kriterium *This answer has severe formatting or content problems.* Dieses Kriterium sehe ich hier erfüllt, weshalb ich die Antwort entsprechend markiert habe.